# How can I transform the string to a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

[image]

As you can see from the picture, when I use StringReplace function, the list is converted to a string. How can I get the list form back? And the String "-" is necessary (Cuz I just know one way to replace "->" to "-").

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. I think you want `Subtract @@@ b3`. But why are you using `Rule` to construct `b3` if what you want is `Subtract`?

Comment: I do not quit understand what you are trying to do, but to get a string back to an expression, you would use: `ToExpression`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post actual data and code rather than images.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

b1 = {a, b, c, d, e};

b2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

b3 = Thread[b1 -> b2];

b4 = StringReplace[ToString /@ b3, "->" -> "-"]

(* {"a - 1", "b - 2", "c - 3", "d - 4", "e - 5"} *)
```

Alternatively, without ever generating `b3`

```
b5 = ToString[#[[1]]] <> " - " <> ToString[#[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{b1, b2}]

(* {"a - 1", "b - 2", "c - 3", "d - 4", "e - 5"} *)
```

The approaches produce identical results.

```
b4 === b5

(* True *)
```

Comment: `b5 = MapThread[ ToString[#1] <> " - " <> ToString[#2] &, {b1, b2}]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
b1 = {a, b, c, d, e};

b2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Some more possibilities:

```
StringRiffle[#, "-"] & /@ Transpose[{b1, b2}]
```

{"a-1", "b-2", "c-3", "d-4", "e-5"}

```
Cases[Transpose[{b1, b2}], x : {_, _} :> StringRiffle[x, "-"]]
```

{"a-1", "b-2", "c-3", "d-4", "e-5"}

```
SequenceCases[Riffle[b1, b2], x : {_, _} :> StringRiffle[x, "-"]]
```

{"a-1", "b-2", "c-3", "d-4", "e-5"}

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I found the answer, the last line I should use b4 = StringReplace[ToString /@ b3, "->" -> "-"].

Answer (score 1):

```
b1 = {a, b, c, d, e};

b2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

---

Using `Thread` and `MapApply`:

```
#1 <> " - " <> #2 & @@@ Map[ToString, Thread[{b1, b2}], {2}]
```

*Result*:

> {"a - 1", "b - 2", "c - 3", "d - 4", "e - 5"}